# How do I add configure an AVPlayer to present an image rather than video?

Tags: swift, image, avplayer, uipageviewcontroller

I have a page view controller - a feed - which an AVPlayer is nested in. How would I configure the AVPlayer to present just an image, or add a switch statement, to present an ImageViewController when an image is loaded into the newsfeed hierarchy?

private func configureVideo() {

```
    guard let path  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mp4") else {
        return
    }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0.5, bottom: 80, right: 0.5))
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player?.volume = 0
    player?.play()
    
        guard let player = player else {
        return
    }
    
    playerDidFinishObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                                     object: player.currentItem,
                                                                     queue: .main
                                                                ) { _ in
                                                                    
        player.seek(to: .zero)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: add imageview or any thing you want above playerlayer